# Remove title bar text of a WPF window but keep status bar text

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I am working in Wpf with metro Window, is it possible to create a window which has text in the taskbar, but has no text in the title bar at the top of the application? 
Currently I am using `<Controls:MetroWindow.LeftWindowCommands>` and `<Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>` for customize my title bar. I have attached images, that doesn't have title text.[image] [image].
And below images have title. 
[image][image]
Now my requirement is that can my application looks like in image 1 and looks like 4th image in task bar

Thanks for your help all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try PInvoke Method.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string text);
```

On Window Loaded :

```
SetWindowText(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, "Madan");
```